# Video Acceleration (VAAPI) broken after upgrading to Ubuntu 17.10 Artful

Tags: graphics, intel-graphics, 17.10, hardware-acceleration, vaapi

I've been using video acceleration (VAAPI) on Ubuntu with my Intel 3D card for several years now, with the drivers (i965) from Oibaf PPA.

Yesterday I upgraded to Artful, added the Oibaf PPA again, updated the drivers and installation seems OK (direct rendering is on), but the hardware acceleration (VAAPI) doesn't work anymore for video.

VLC plays the video without acceleration, when I run it from the commandline it says "vaapi_x11 generic error: Failed to initialize the VAAPI device". I run vainfo to get information, and it says "Can't connect to X server!", but then shows all VAProfiles correctly.

Have you experienced a similar problem? Do you guys have any suggestions? Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1):

There is an already reported issue that affect most applications using vaapi in a Wayland session.

The bug's details are reported here with a some partial workarounds:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/vlc/+bug/1698287

You can also avoid the issue by not using the wayland session, using Gnome/ubuntu on X.org or using Unity.